# Create groups based on time period

Tags: r

How can I create a new grouping variable for my data based on 5-year steps?

So from this:

```
group <- c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 10))
year <- c(2008:2014, 2005:2014)
dat <- data.frame(group, year)

   group year
1      A 2008
2      A 2009
3      A 2010
4      A 2011
5      A 2012
6      A 2013
7      A 2014
8      B 2005
9      B 2006
10     B 2007
11     B 2008
12     B 2009
13     B 2010
14     B 2011
15     B 2012
16     B 2013
17     B 2014
```

To this:

```
 > dat
   group year    period
1      A 2008 2005_2009
2      A 2009 2005_2009
3      A 2010 2010_2014
4      A 2011 2010_2014
5      A 2012 2010_2014
6      A 2013 2010_2014
7      A 2014 2010_2014
8      B 2005 2005_2009
9      B 2006 2005_2009
10     B 2007 2005_2009
11     B 2008 2005_2009
12     B 2009 2005_2009
13     B 2010 2010_2014
14     B 2011 2010_2014
15     B 2012 2010_2014
16     B 2013 2010_2014
17     B 2014 2010_2014
```

I guess I could use `cut(dat$year, breaks = ??)` but I don't know how to set the breaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
dat$period <- paste(min <- floor(dat$year/5)*5, min+4,sep = "_")
```

I guess the trick here is to get the biggest whole number smaller than your year with the `floor(year/x)*x` function.

---

Here is a version that should work generally:

```
x <- 5
yearstart <- 2000
dat$period <- paste(min <- floor((dat$year-yearstart)/x)*x+yearstart,
                    min+x-1,sep = "_")
```

You can use `yearstart` to ensure e.g. year 2000 is the first in a group for when `x` is not a multiple of it.

Comment: Very nicely done. I think it will be hard to beat that one efficiency wise.

Comment: Thanks, works well for my example. But is it possible to adjust to intervals of e.g. 10 years (creates an interval 2010_1019 if I try)?

Comment: 10 years work for me as well: `paste(min <- floor(dat$year/10)*10, min+9,sep = "_")`. Nice solution!

Comment: @beetroot I have added a general example!

Comment: You can avoid to use `floor` and use the integer division `%/%` instead. `(dat$year%/%5)*5` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` should do the job if you create actual `Date` objects from your 'year' column.

```
## convert 'year' column to dates
yrs <- paste0(dat$year, "-01-01")
yrs <- as.Date(yrs)

## create cuts of 5 years and add them to data.frame
dat$period <- cut(yrs, "5 years")

## create desired factor levels
library(lubridate)

lvl <- as.Date(levels(dat$period))
lvl <- paste(year(lvl), year(lvl) + 4, sep = "_")
levels(dat$period) <- lvl

head(dat)
  group year    period
1     A 2008 2005_2009
2     A 2009 2005_2009
3     A 2010 2010_2014
4     A 2011 2010_2014
5     A 2012 2010_2014
6     A 2013 2010_2014
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to create the levels of period non-manually? My actual dataset spans more than 200 years so that would be tedious...

Comment: Sure @beetroot. Have a look at the above update. Just use `year` from **lubridate** to create the start and end point of each period.